# Need a working algorithm to find out optimal kernel bandwidth for density estimation

Tags: estimation, model-selection, density-function, kernel-smoothing

I am looking for a working algorithm for find out optimal kernel bandwidth for density estimation.   I need to write my own program in pascal instead of using R or Matlab.  So far all algorithms I found failed.  For example, this one looks simple and promising:

http://www.di.ubi.pt/~lfbaa/entnetsPubs/bandwidth.pdf

I wrote the following program for it:

```
program test;
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
function hopt(data: array of Double): Double;
var
  h0, h1, k4, s: Double;
  i, j, n: Integer;
begin
  n := Length(data);
  //Silverman's value to start with
  //stdev_p() simply calculate the population standard deviation
  h0 := 1.06*stdev_p(data)*power(n,-0.2); 
  while True do begin
    //start of formula-17
    k4 := 0;
    for i := 0 to n - 1 do begin
      for j := 0 to i - 1 do begin
        s := sqr(data[i] - data[j]);
        k4 += (sqr(s-6*h0*h0)-24*power(h0,4))*exp(-s/4/h0/h0);
      end;
    end;
    k4 := 3*n*h0+k4/2/power(h0,3);
    h1 := power(4*n*power(h0,6)/k4,0.2);
    //end of formula-17
    h1 := (h0+h1)/2;
    if abs(h1-h0) < 0.0001 then Break;
    h0 := h1;
  end;
  Result := h1;
end;
var
  a: array of Double;
begin
  SetLength(a, 6);
  a[0] := -2.1;
  a[1] := -1.3;
  a[2] := -0.4;
  a[3] := 1.9;
  a[4] := 5.1;
  a[5] := 6.2;  
  WriteLn('hopt=', hopt(a));
end.
```

Using this sample to test the above function: -2.1, -1.3, -0.4, 1.9, 5.1, 6.2

The result it gives is 3.716, which is much worse than initial Silverman value 2.335.  Using R's sm::hsj() on this data set, the optimal h value is around 1.9, which is rather close to wikipedia's 1.5.

I have also tried cross-validation method suggested here:

http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A6n18.pdf?origin=publication_detail

which does not converge at all.

Could anyone explain a simple way, be it cross-validation, or plug-in method, using a small data set, rather than math formula or proprietary languages such as R or matlab?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I contacted Dr. Alexandre, author of the first article I referred.  His C version program output same result as my pascal.